# Why does my struct vale keep changing as my loop goes?

Tags: c

I'm trying to loop through a csv file line fore line and assign the values to a struct called cards. my loop goes through the file add assign values to cards[x] but every time my code loops though it keeps change old values like cards[0];

```
#include "card.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int num_entries = 0;
    card_t **cards = NULL;
    int freeCards = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t bufsiz = 0;
    int x = 0;
    FILE *input_file = fopen("short-cards-1.csv", "r");
    ssize_t result;
    getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file);
    while ( (result = getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file)) > 0){
        num_entries++;

        cards = realloc(cards, sizeof(card_t *) * num_entries);
        cards[x] = malloc(sizeof(card_t));

        printf("x:            %d\n",x);
        printf("===============\n" );
        char *stringp = buf;
        int id  = atoi(strsep(&stringp, ","));
        cards[x]->id = id;
        printf("ID:   %d\n", cards[x]->id);
        //get name
        stringp++;
        cards[x]->name = strsep(&stringp, "\"");
        printf("%s\n",cards[x]->name);
        //get cost
        stringp += 2;
        //printf("Cost: %s\n",strsep(&stringp, "\""));
        cards[x]->cost = strsep(&stringp, "\"");
        printf("Cost: %s\n",cards[x]->cost);

        printf("===================\n");
        printf("ID:   %d\n", cards[0]->id);
        printf("Cost: %s\n",cards[0]->name);
        printf("Cost: %s\n",cards[0]->cost);
        printf("===============\n\n\n" );
        x++;
    }
    printf("===============\n");
    printf("%d \n",cards[0]->id);

    freeCards = 0;
    while (freeCards < num_entries){
        free(cards[freeCards]);
        freeCards++;
    }
    free(cards);
    free(buf);
    fclose(input_file);
    return 0;

}
```

```
enum rarity
{
    common,
    uncommon,
    rare,
    mythic
};

typedef struct card
{
    unsigned int id;
    char* name;
    char* cost;
    unsigned int converted_cost;
    char* type;
    char* text;
    char* stats;
    enum rarity rarity;
} card_t;
```

```
output
x:            0
===============
ID:   198981
Stolen by the Fae
Cost: {X}{U}{U}
===================
ID:   198981
Cost: Stolen by the Fae
Cost: {X}{U}{U}
===============


x:            1
===============
ID:   192783
Eternal Isolation
Cost: {1}{W}
===================
ID:   198981
Cost: Eternal Isolation
Cost: {1}{W}
===============


x:            2
===============
ID:   192783
Eternal Isolation
Cost: {1}{W}
===================
ID:   198981
Cost: Eternal Isolation
Cost: {1}{W}
===============


x:            3
===============
ID:   192504
Corpse Knight
Cost: {W}{B}
===================
ID:   198981
Cost: Corpse Knight
Cost: B}
===============


x:            4
===============
ID:   183427
Orzhov Enforcer
Cost: {1}{B}
===================
ID:   198981
Cost: Orzhov Enforcer
Cost: }{B}
===============
```

I don't get my cards[0] is being changed when the new values are assigned to cards[x] and x is never 0 after the first loop;

Comment: i should also add in that the Id value never changes but the rest do

Comment: Well, the other members are strings and require allocated space and strcpy to load the structs.

Comment: am i not allocating space here ```cards = realloc(cards, sizeof(card_t *) * num_entries);
  cards[x] = malloc(sizeof(card_t));```

Comment: You are not allocating space for the string member `cards[x].name` etc to point to.  Instead you are assigning to it the return value of `strsep`, which is a pointer into the buffer `buf`, which gets overwritten every time you need a new line.  If you want to save the string, you need to `malloc` space for the string and copy it there.  Or use `strdup` which does both at once, if your system provides it.

Comment: "_i should also add in_": Well, then please [edit] your question and add it. Please take the [tour] to learn how to use SO, as this is not a forum. ;-)